# Call generic type instance method

Tags: java, generics

I have implemented Generic DAO for all my bean classes. I am facing a problem in setting the entries in to the cache.

> DAO.class

```
public abstract class DAO<T extends Serializable> extends Cache
{
    save(Collection<T> list)
    {
        // batch process will store the list to db

        for(T t : list)
        {
             cache(t.getKey(), t);
        }
    }
}
```

> Bean's DAO classes

```
public class BeanDAO1 extends DAO<Bean1>
{
    public static set(Collection<Bean1> list)
    {
        super.save(list);
    }
}

 public class BeanDAO2 extends DAO<Bean2>
{
    public static set(Collection<Bean2> list)
    {
        super.save(list);
    }
}
```

Now the problem is, both Bean classes have same getter method `getKey()`. But in DAO class, as it is type referenced, i couldn't access the method.

Is it something i am doing wrong or I should do some other thing?

Answer (score 1):

In your `save` method you access the method `getKey()` on objects of type `T`. For that you must constrain that type variable to be a subtype of a type that has this method. As it is, the only thing the compiler know that your `T` is a subtype of `Serializable` (which doesn't have this method).

That means you should have a supertype for all your beans:

```
public interface Bean extends Serializable {
    public ? getKey(); // I do not know what type your keys are
}
```

Your bean classes should implement this interface. Then you can do the following:

```
public abstract class DAO<T extends Bean> extends Cache {
    public save(Collection<T> list) {
        for(T t : list) {
            cache(t.getKey(), t);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: an interface can extend another interface and cannot implement it

Comment: While you are correct that type T of DAO class must be Serializable as well as extend Bean type,in practice interfaces should not be marked Serializable as it is a marker interface and classes implementing it will not know that there classes have been marked Serializable and fields may be missed from being marked as transient where they themselves cannot be Serialized

Comment: @KumarAbhinav I corrected the implements/extends mistake. Additional, I didn't want to make it too complicated and this was the easiest way to be conform to the original implementation.

Comment: I removed the downvoting

Answer (score 0):

Your type declaration `T extends Serializable` is too broad. You must define a class implementing or an interface extending `Serializable` that has an abstract method `getKey()` and let `T` extend this new type.

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest solution as @Ray suggested is having a common interface for Entity classes such as:

```
public abstract class DAO<T extends AbstractEntity> extends Cache
{
    save(Collection<T> list)
    {
        // batch process will store the list to db

        for(T t : list)
        {
             cache(t.getKey(), t);
        }
    }
}
```

And the interface:

```
public interface AbstractEntity
{

}
```

**EDIT:**

And having **Bean1** and **Bean2** implement the interface as such:

```
public class Bean1 implements AbstractEntity
{

}

public class Bean2 implements AbstractEntity
{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The marker interface `Serializable` doesn't define getKey() method.However,your type `T` can declare multiple upper bounds.Let your Bean1 and Bean2 extend a common super class or inteface which has a getKey() method

```
interface Bean{

   Object getKey();
}

class Bean1 implements Bean,Serializable {

   public String getKey(){
  /// 
   }
}

class Bean2 implements Bean,Serializable{

   public String getKey(){
  /// 
   }
}
public abstract class DAO<T extends Bean & Serializable> extends Cache
{
    save(Collection<T> list)
    {
        // batch process will store the list to db

        for(T t : list)
        {
             cache(t.getKey(), t);
        }
    }
}
public class BeanDAO1 extends DAO<Bean1>
{
    public static set(Collection<Bean1> list)
    {
        super.save(list);
    }
}

 public class BeanDAO2 extends DAO<Bean2>
{
    public static set(Collection<Bean2> list)
    {
        super.save(list);
    }
}
```